# Trouble with Nvidia driver under Loki

Tags: boot, graphic-drivers, nvidia, kernel

I installed the Nvidia driver using Ubuntu method (Addition drivers tab under software & updates). It works great so far, but every time Elementary updates kernel system would not boot up. The only way is to boot the previous kernel version, uninstall Nvidia. Boot the current kernel and install Nvidia again. This is a strange behavior omho. My previous distro was OpenSuSE and it never had a problem like that.
Does anyone know what to do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: it passed after manual installation of dkms-nvidia

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup and then re-install elementary OS. That fixed it for me.

Don't use "software update".

Answer (score 0):

First, you should removed everything related with nvidia

```
sudo apt-get remove bumblebee (if installed)
sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
```

And add the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

List the drivers and install them
you should turn the secure boot in BIOS

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Now you will see the "PRIME Profiles" section in nvidia-settings screen. you can select Intel or nvidia.

reboot or log out and login in.

If you want a software to manage your GPU,then installing primus with:

```
sudo apt-get install primus
```

With primus, bumblebee is also installed.

Next, edit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

```
driver=nvidia
KernelDriver=nvidia-367
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-367:/usr/lib32/nvidia-367
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-367/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
```

NOTE: nvidia-367 is your version, you should change the numbers for your nvidia driver version

Reboot